# memory leak in node regex parser?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, memory-leaks

The following code causes node to consume a lot of ram and crash when it runs out of memory. However if I change the length of the found string from 13 to 12 everything is fine. It looks as if strings returned by a regex search contain a hidden reference to the original string that was searched. But only if the length of the found match is at least 13 characters.
Is this a bug or is there some good reason for that behavior?

```
function randString(length) {
  var a = "a".charCodeAt(0),
      result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result.push(a + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26));
  }
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, result);
}


var arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
  if(i % 1000 === 0) console.log(i);
  var str = randString(13);
  str = randString(5000) + "<" +str + ">" + randString(5000);
  var re = /<([a-z]+)>/gm;
  var next = re.exec(str);
  arr.push(next[1]);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the 12-character version isn't also using a lot of memory, but just not enough to make it crash?

Comment: The 12 character version uses less than 100 MB. But with 13 or more characters it will get to 1.5GB within only 145,000 iterations.

Comment: I observe the same thing in Chrome (Version 41.0.2272.76 Built on Ubuntu 14.04, running on LinuxMint 17 (64-bit))

Answer (score 3):

I observe the same behavior in Chrome. I think the two (node.js and Chrome) behave the same because they are based on the same Javascript engine ([V8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V8_%28JavaScript_engine%29)).

There is no memory leak, but there is a problem with the garbage management in Javascript. I deduct this from the observation, that the Gbytes of memory are freed when I force garbage collection in Google Dev Tools.

You could force to run the garbage collector, as [explained here](https://simonmcmanus.wordpress.com/2013/01/03/forcing-garbage-collection-with-node-js-and-v8/). That way, your node.js will not crash.

**Edit**

Testing further I can tell these things:

About your comment *But as long as there is still a reference to the array no memory get's freed.*:

It looks more complicated than that, but you are right, `arr` seems to occupy all that space 1.1 Go for 100'000 items, this is 10kB per item. When you look at the array `next`, it indeed has a size of roughly 10kB (10015 bytes for `next.input`. If all worked like expected, `next[1]` would be a simple string and use only slighly more than the 13 data bytes, but this is not the case. Referencing `next[1]` in the array `arr` does not allow `next` to be garbage collected.

As a solution, I came up with this modified code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lmeyer1/c2545qmd/3/)):

```
function randString(length) {
  var a = "a".charCodeAt(0),
      result = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    result.push(a + Math.floor(Math.random() * 26));
  }
  return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, result);
}


var arr = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
  if(i % 1000 === 0) console.log(i);
  var str = randString(13);
  str = randString(5000) + "<" +str + ">" + randString(5000);
  var re = /<([a-z]+)>/gm;
  var next = re.exec(str);
  arr.push(next[1].split('').join(''));
}
console.log(arr)
```

The trick is to cut the reference between `next` and the string stored in `arr` by splitting the string and joining it again.

I don't know anything about the internals, but it looks like a bug in V8. Testing the same on Firefox, everything works as expected, and there is no excessive memory usage.

Comment: Running the garbage collector doesn't have any effect. You probably define `arr` inside a function and when that returns `arr` can get garbage collected. But as long as there is still a reference to the array no memory get's freed.

Comment: I can't test on node.js, but in Google Chrome garbage collection frees most of the memory. Look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/lmeyer1/c2545qmd/2/, after running it click on *Collect garbage* in the *Timeline* tab of devtools.

Comment: OK, it becomes more and more interesting. When I console.log(arr) at the end (to keep a reference), the *Collect garbage* button doesn't collect anymore, but when I launch all a second time (with keeping the reference in the console), the garbage collector jumps in automatically.

Comment: Yes, and at the same time the console looses it's reference to the array. Because of that you can't expand it anymore. Also js code in jsfiddle doesn't run at top level. It's wrapped inside a function. If you type `arr` into the console it will give you a reference error.

Comment: You're right. I didn't notice that the object in the console is no longer expandable. I can't explain that odd behavior, but at least I found a valid workaround. See my edit.

Comment: Holding reference to the captured string actually holds reference to the whole original string. This is a performance trick to avoid excessive memory allocation for every regex capture. This workaround definitely cuts the link to the original reference, thus fixing the "memory leak" problem.

Comment: next[1].split('').join('') worked out awesome! This really reduce the memory from 1.5GB to 6MB. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found the source of the problem. It's not the regexp parser that's responsible for this but the substring method on strings. It's intended as a feature for making the creation of substrings more efficient.
There is an open issue about this on the V8 bug report page.
https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2869